# What's the difference between `yarn add react-router-dom` and `yarn add @types/react-router-dom`?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router, yarnpkg

Doing

`yarn add react-router-dom`

fails.  The app throws an error on startup and Intellij flags the import from `react-router-dom` it as an error.  But doing

`yarn add @types/react-router-dom`

works.

All the examples I've found except for one show the first `yarn add...` command, though.  Is this something new with `react-router-dom`?

I'm using typescript if that makes any difference.

===Edit===

Here is the error message.  This is where I found the solution.

```
/home/dean/src/react/projects/room-reservations-ui_/src/App.tsx
TypeScript error in /home/dean/src/react/projects/room-reservations-ui_/src/App.tsx(5,29):
Could not find a declaration file for module 'react-router-dom'. '/home/dean/src/react/projects/room-reservations-ui_/node_modules/react-router-dom/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
  Try `npm i --save-dev @types/react-router-dom` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'react-router-dom';`  TS7016

    3 | import './App.css';
    4 | import Navbar from "./components/Navbar";
  > 5 | import {BrowserRouter} from "react-router-dom";
      |                             ^
    6 | 
    7 | function App() {
    8 |   return (
```

Comment: What is the error with `yarn add react-router-dom`? The one from `@types` is just another package under a `@types` organization(https://docs.npmjs.com/about-organization-scopes-and-packages), they aren't that related although one provides the typing for the other, I believe you could be getting errors because the types are not found for the first package

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
yarn add react-router-dom
```

This is installing `react-router-dom`, without any types, if you try to start your app just with this package, you will see the message you got

```
Could not find a declaration file for module 'react-router-dom'.
```

This doesn't mean that there is an error with the `react-router-dom`, but Typescript don't have the types declared for it, the project could have been made with Javascript, or the type declarations are somewhere else.

```
yarn add @types/react-router-dom
```

This will install the types for react-router-dom from DefinitelyTyped(https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped), this is a repository where declarations are made so we can install types for libraries that were made just for Javascript, but someone else "typed" it for us.

```
@types/
```

This prefix is an organization, which will refer to the react-router-dom package inside the DefinitelyTyped repository, it doesn`t contain react-router-dom code, only the type definitions, which you can see here https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/types/react-router-dom

It contains only the declaration, when Typescript can't find declarations for a module you are using, it won't be able to correctly show you the types, so it gives the warning

Comment: I've accepted your answer, but other packages didn't need the `@types` prefix:

`yarn add @material-ui/core
yarn add @material-ui/icons`

both worked.

Comment: Material ui already has the type definitions on their components, for example, https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/next/packages/material-ui/src/Accordion/Accordion.d.ts the `@types` organization is useful when the package has no types on its own or the authors wanted it to be there

Answer (score 2):

Simply put, `@types/react-router-dom` contains type definitions. It is intended for use with typescript. you can see more about this   [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/react-router-dom).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Just removed `rrd` from node modules with types and installed it again

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).